# ordering the results of a full join in sql

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have 2 tables on which I am doing a full outer join.Both the tables have a timestamp column. I want the result of the join to be ordered by the timestamp. such that say table a has rows

### Table A

```
X           timestamp           
92408413    12/22/2011 11:23:36 AM  
92408414    12/22/2011 11:23:40 AM
92408417    12/22/2011 11:23:45 AM
92408419    12/22/2011 11:23:49 AM
92408423    12/22/2011 11:23:55 AM
92408424    12/22/2011 11:23:57 AM
92408426    12/22/2011 11:24:01 AM
92408427    12/22/2011 11:24:09 AM
92408430    12/22/2011 11:24:33 AM
92408435    12/22/2011 11:25:03 AM
92408437    12/22/2011 11:25:13 AM
92408497    12/22/2011 11:31:09 AM
92408498    12/22/2011 11:31:10 AM
92408499    12/22/2011 11:31:12 AM
```

### table B

```
Y               X                timestamp
5020926963  92408430    12/22/2011 11:24:33 AM
5020926968  92408435    12/22/2011 11:25:03 AM
5020926970  92408435    12/22/2011 11:25:05 AM
5020926972  92408437    12/22/2011 11:25:14 AM
5020926981  -1      12/22/2011 11:31:09 AM
5020926982  -1      12/22/2011 11:31:10 AM
5020926984  92408499    12/22/2011 11:31:12 AM
```

Now if my query looks something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tablea 
       FULL OUTER JOIN tableb 
         ON tablea.x = tableb.x 
            AND tablea.w = tableb.w 
WHERE  tablea.x = 'somevalue' 
        OR tableb.x = 'somevalue' 
ORDER  BY tablea.timestamp, 
          tableb.timestamp
```

The result of the query is :

```
92408413    12/22/2011 11:23:36 AM      
92408414    12/22/2011 11:23:40 AM      
92408417    12/22/2011 11:23:45 AM      
92408419    12/22/2011 11:23:49 AM      
92408423    12/22/2011 11:23:55 AM      
92408424    12/22/2011 11:23:57 AM      
92408426    12/22/2011 11:24:01 AM      
92408427    12/22/2011 11:24:09 AM      
92408430    12/22/2011 11:24:33 AM  5020926963  12/22/2011 11:24:33 AM
92408435    12/22/2011 11:25:03 AM  5020926968  12/22/2011 11:25:03 AM
92408435    12/22/2011 11:25:03 AM  5020926970  12/22/2011 11:25:05 AM
92408437    12/22/2011 11:25:13 AM  5020926972  12/22/2011 11:25:14 AM
92408497    12/22/2011 11:31:09 AM      
92408498    12/22/2011 11:31:10 AM      
92408499    12/22/2011 11:31:12 AM  5020926984  12/22/2011 11:31:12 AM
                                5020926981      12/22/2011 11:31:09 AM
                                5020926982  12/22/2011 11:31:10 AM
```

Now, this query first orders by TableA's tiemstamp and then TableB's. I want the result to be odered by timestamp(in order of time).So basically ordering by (TableA.timestamp + TableB.timestamp). As you can see there is a row in Table A where the timestamp is 
    ' 92408497 12/22/2011 11:31:09 AM' 
I want the next row in the result to have a column from Table B which has the same timestamp 
    ' 5020926981    -1      12/22/2011 11:31:09 AM'

I am on a Oracle 11.2 database.

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
order by coalesce (table1.timestamp, table2.timestamp)
```